# Limit records in SonataAdminBundle by user

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm building a SaaS application using Symfony2, and I'm using SonataAdminBundle to create the CRUD of the common entities (like type of members, languages, etc; common entities to all users that can only be created and modified by administrators).

I also want to use SonataAdminBundle for the SaaS entities: the entities that belongs to an user, but I don't know how to do it... As far as I know, I can use an event listener to add the owner information to the entity when saving, but how can I limit the records an user can see?

What I want is that when a user logs in he's redirected to the dashboard. Then, when he clicks on the "Members" entities, he sees a list of all **his members**, but he **shouldn't** see any member from the other users.

Is this behavior possible with SonataAdmin, or I must create my own CRUD functions? If it's possible, can you explain (or show any tutorial/document) about how to create this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `createQuery` to alter the query used to list entities: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Admin/Admin.php#L1399-L1408

You can also create an extension if this logic need to be done for many admin instances.